# I want to create a pointer to a char value in C++ and get its size, but it doesn't display anything

Tags: c++

This is a snippet code found in a book that I can't fully understand. The chapter was about various data types.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    char c = 'c';
    char minCharValue = std::numeric_limits<char>::min();
    char maxCharValue = std::numeric_limits<char>::max();
    printf("Char: size %zu \n\t - min val is %d \n \t - max val is %d\n", sizeof(c), minCharValue, maxCharValue);

    bool b = false; // can be {true, false}
    printf("Bool: %zu\n", sizeof(b));

    int i = -560;
    int minIntValue = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int maxIntValue = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    printf("int: size %zu \n\t - min val is %d \n \t - max val is %d \n", sizeof(i), minIntValue, maxIntValue);

    getchar();

    // pointers
    char *p = &c;
    printf("Pointer to char: %zu\n", sizeof(p));
    printf("Pointer to int: %zu\n", sizeof(int*));
    printf("Pointer to double: %zu\n", sizeof(double*));

    return 0;
}
```

This specific part is what I don't understand. What is getchar() supposed to do? Why can't I print the last statements regarding that pointer?

```
 getchar();

    // pointers
    char *p = &c;
    printf("Pointer to char: %zu\n", sizeof(p));
    printf("Pointer to int: %zu\n", sizeof(int*));
    printf("Pointer to double: %zu\n", sizeof(double*));
```

Comment: Did you press enter?

Comment: [`std::getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/getchar)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux it still doesn't work :(

Comment: @SeverienneBianca What doesn't work? My comment was a link to documentation for the function you are asking about.

Comment: Doesn't the same book explain `getchar()`? If seems like a bad book if it doesn't.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Haha right, sorry, I'm not very used to using this site and I didn't think it was a hyperlink :) thanks, it was useful. My problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

The `getchar` is just to help you see what output comes from before that line of code and what output comes from after it. It waits for you to press enter.

Comment: `getchar()` is the C way to get a character from stdin.  The C++ way is `std::cin.get()` instead.